# Handling Page Reloads With OAuth Access Code In URI

Tags: google-app-engine, http, post, oauth, oauth-2.0

I've run into an issue when using OAuth 2 authorization codes in an web app's URL, such as is returned by Google's OAuth method (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login).

I've been using the google redirect method; where you redirect the user to a Google URL, passing in client_id and redirect_uri. The user authenticates and the authorization code is passed to the redirect_uri as a

The issue is that the access code stays in the page URL, so if the user bookmarks or posts the URL, they are sending an invalid Authorization Code.

Eg:

```
http://myapp.com/?code=kACASDSDdAS81J5B8M_owCyUNgV46XdZaqBBMh4T8OJFEKPRrgN7gtiFOcMW5Fv3gk
```

What is the best way to handle this case? Ideally, I would like to send the authorization code in a POST body as it isn't visible to the player?

I've spent a bit of time looking at Google App Engine (the platform I'm using) to redirect the user, but can't seem to send a POST body in a redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the user is directed to your app with the authorization code in the URL query parameter, you should:

1) Exchange the authorization code for an access token by making a HTTPs POST to Google's OAuth 2.0 token endpoint and save that access token as appropriate (datastore, memcache, etc)

2) Redirect the user to a URL without the `?code`.  You can't send a POST body in a redirect (HTTP doesn't allow it), but that shouldn't be necessary if you store the access token server-side for making API calls.

If you must make the token accessible client-side, you can:

a) Send it back as a cookie along with the redirect (which exposes it to the client, though you could encrypt it) OR

b) Generate a HTML form, with JavaScript for auto-submitting it instead of doing the redirect.  Kind of ugly, but common.

Comment: Cookie will expire and the problem will be the same. Form with autosubmit will pose some questions about security.

Comment: @Artem - Access tokens are often only valid for an hour.  Plus you can save the cookie as long-lived (years if you want).  I don't recommend sending the access token back to the client when using the authorization code mechanism, but these are two valid ways to do it if the developer insists :)